# What happens when the depth of the slit varies in the double slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

What meaningful effect is there if the depth of the slit varies with respect to the wavelength?

[image]

Cases:

1. D < λ
2. D = λ
3. D > λ

Answer (score 0):

Good question but I believe the pattern is unaffected.  Just the intensity would decrease with increased thickness as photons have to be on smaller path angles to make it through.